# BindView not firing so listview blank

Tags: android, listview, cursor

I have a custom cursor adaptor which seems to be mostly working, except for the bindView method. I have Log calls inside bindView which are never appearing in my logCat. The listView I create is being displayed with the correct number of rows but the rows are blank. The onCLickListener is also working fine and logcat shows it has read rows from the database.

Code is as follows - in my activity:

```
// build a listView adapter
        Log.i(LOGTAG,"About to create listView...");
        tripList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        //tripList = getListView();
        Log.i(LOGTAG,"ListView created...");

        Log.i(LOGTAG,"About to create adapter...");
        tripAdapter = new tripListAdapter(this, tripCur);
        //setListAdapter(tripAdapter);
        tripList.setAdapter(tripAdapter);

        tripList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                // Do something in response to the click
                // Enable other buttons
                togBtns(true);

                // set global variable to show which ID was clicked on
                listTripPosClicked = position;

                // Get details from display, of clicked item
                TextView tmpDate = (TextView) tripList.findViewById(R.id.dateFld);
                TextView tmpDist = (TextView) tripList.findViewById(R.id.distFld);
                TextView tmpMPG = (TextView) tripList.findViewById(R.id.mpgFld);

                // store these for sending to doTripActivity
                clickedDist = tmpDist.getText().toString();
                clickedDate = tmpDate.getText().toString();
                clickedMPG = tmpMPG.getText().toString();

                Log.i(LOGTAG, "Dist = " + clickedDist);
                Log.i(LOGTAG, "Date = " + clickedDate);
                Log.i(LOGTAG, "mpg = " + clickedMPG);

            }
        });
```

Adaptor code is:

```
// custom list adaptor class
private class tripListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    //private final Cursor dataC;
    private final LayoutInflater vi;
    public View theView;

    public tripListAdapter(Context con, Cursor c) {
        // super constructor thingy
        super(con, c);
        //dataC = c;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(con);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View v, ViewGroup parent){

        Log.i(LOGTAG,"In getView...");
        // Create a message handling object as an anonymous class.
        //mTripClickHandler = new OnItemClickListener() {
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.trip_row, parent, false);

        Log.i(LOGTAG,"Leaving getView...");
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context arg1, Cursor dataC) {
        Log.i(LOGTAG,"In bindView...");
        // get data from cursor
        TextView dateTV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dateFld);
        TextView distTV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.distFld);
        TextView mpgTV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mpgFld);

        String tmpMPG = dataC.getString(dataC.getColumnIndexOrThrow(dbHistory.TRIP_MPG));
        Double tmpNum = Double.valueOf(tmpMPG);
        tmpMPG = String.format("%.2f", tmpNum);

        dateTV.setText(dataC.getString(dataC.getColumnIndexOrThrow(dbHistory.TRIP_DATE)));
        distTV.setText(dataC.getString(dataC.getColumnIndexOrThrow(dbHistory.TRIP_MILES)));
        mpgTV.setText(tmpMPG);                      

        Log.i(LOGTAG,"Leaving bindView...");
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context arg0, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(LOGTAG,"In newView...");
        //theView = vi.inflate(R.layout.trip_row, arg2, false);

        Log.i(LOGTAG,"Leaving newView...");
        return theView;
    }
}
```

Output from logCat shows the various Log messages but nothing from bindView, which I guess is why my listView is blank.

```
06-17 06:40:31.827: I/WIBBLE(866): About to create listView...
06-17 06:40:31.827: I/WIBBLE(866): ListView created...
06-17 06:40:31.838: I/WIBBLE(866): About to create adapter...
06-17 06:40:31.838: I/WIBBLE(866): OnResume with this many rows returned by cursor: 3
06-17 06:40:31.838: I/WIBBLE(866): In the loop, so cursor is not null....
06-17 06:40:31.897: I/WIBBLE(866): In getView...
06-17 06:40:31.917: I/WIBBLE(866): Leaving getView...
06-17 06:40:31.917: I/WIBBLE(866): In getView...
06-17 06:40:31.937: I/WIBBLE(866): Leaving getView...
06-17 06:40:31.957: I/WIBBLE(866): In getView...
06-17 06:40:31.967: I/WIBBLE(866): Leaving getView...
06-17 06:40:32.137: I/WIBBLE(866): In getView...
06-17 06:40:32.217: I/WIBBLE(866): Leaving getView...
06-17 06:40:32.279: I/WIBBLE(866): In getView...
06-17 06:40:32.347: I/WIBBLE(866): Leaving getView...
06-17 06:40:32.417: I/WIBBLE(866): In getView...
06-17 06:40:32.427: I/WIBBLE(866): Leaving getView...
06-17 06:40:32.959: I/Choreographer(866): Skipped 116 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-17 06:40:34.056: I/WIBBLE(866): In getView...
06-17 06:40:34.147: I/WIBBLE(866): Leaving getView...
06-17 06:40:34.197: I/WIBBLE(866): In getView...
06-17 06:40:34.267: I/WIBBLE(866): Leaving getView...
06-17 06:40:34.289: I/WIBBLE(866): In getView...
06-17 06:40:34.308: I/WIBBLE(866): Leaving getView...
06-17 06:40:39.486: I/WIBBLE(866): Dist = 
06-17 06:40:39.486: I/WIBBLE(866): Date = 
06-17 06:40:39.496: I/WIBBLE(866): mpg =
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: That's happening because you overridden the `getView()`  method(which calls `newView()` and `bindView()` in its implementation). Remove it and inflate the layout in `newView()`.

Comment: What is theView? Are you initing it at the right place?

Comment: @Luksprog - brilliant - many thanks! I thought I had tried that (see commented out inflate command in newView) but obviously not. Thanks again...if you add it as an answer, I'll mark it up for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Cursor` based adapters the `getView()` method is implemented to call the `newView()` and `bindView()` methods. If you override it like you did, without calling `super()` those methods will not be called. So, remove the overridden `getView()` method and inflate the row layout in the `newView()` method.

Also, for `Cursor` based adapter you generally don't override the `getView()` method, you work with its two delegate methods that you need to override.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a smaple which is working fine for me:

```
private class CurAdapter extends CursorAdapter{


        boolean imageExists;


        public CurAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
            super(context, c, flags);

        }


        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


            //  String isAdhoc = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("isAdhoc")));
            String name = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Name")));
            String image = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("imageUri"));
            String manuplate = dateConvert(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("BirthDate")));


            //  if(isAdhoc.equals("1")){

            tv.setText(name);


            if(manuplate.contains("0001")){
                manuplate = manuplate.replace("0001", "");
            }
            tv1.setText((manuplate));
            tv.setTypeface(tf, Typeface.BOLD);
            tv1.setTypeface(tf1); 

            //  System.out.println("Image Uri is:"+image);


            if(image.contains("jpg") || image.contains("png")){
                File f = new File(image);
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
                iv.setImageBitmap(bmp); 




            }else{
                Uri IMAGE_URI = null;
                IMAGE_URI = Uri.parse(image);
                IMAGE_URI= Uri.withAppendedPath(IMAGE_URI, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
                try{
                    iv.setImageURI(IMAGE_URI);
                    iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP); 


                }catch (Exception e){
                    imageExists = false; 

                }
            }
            if (!imageExists){

                iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.default_img);
                iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP); 
                //      }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.contacts_list, null);

            /*  view.setTag(R.id.textView1, tv);
            view.setTag(R.id.textView2, tv1);
            view.setTag(R.id.imageView1, iv); */
            return view;

        }
}
```